# Virtex-7 FPGA Clock Constraint Configuration

Tags: fpga, differential, xilinx, virtex-series-fpga

I am moving from entry level FPGA such as Artix-7 (BASYS-3 board) to using a Virtex-7 (VC709 board). I have a question about how to setup the constraints file for the main clock of the Virtex-7 FPGA. The user guide is found here: https://docs.amd.com/v/u/en-US/ug887-vc709-eval-board-v7-fpga and the clock documentation starts at pages 28.

There are 6 different clocks on the VC709 board. I think using the system clock is best place to start. It is 200MHz differential clock. Here is the simple hardware design I want to validate to get the Virtex-7 up and running:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

entity top_level is
  Port (clk_p_i : in std_logic;
        clk_n_i : in std_logic;
        reset_button_i : in std_logic;
        led0_o  : out std_logic     
       );
end top_level;

architecture Behavioral of top_level is

component clk_wiz_0
port
 (clk_out1  : out    std_logic;
  clk_in1_p : in     std_logic;
  clk_in1_n : in     std_logic
 );
end component;

signal clk_50MHz : std_logic;
signal led_buf   : std_logic;

begin

--- Clocking Wizard ---
clk_wix_inst : clk_wiz_0 port map
  (clk_out1  => clk_50MHz,
   clk_in1_p => clk_p_i,
   clk_in1_n => clk_n_i
  );

--- LED Logic ---
Process (clk_50MHz, reset_button_i)

begin

if (reset_button_i = '1') then
    led_buf <= '0';

elsif (rising_edge(clk_50MHz)) then
    led_buf <= '1';
    
end if;

end Process;

led0_o <= led_buf;

end Behavioral;
```

And here is the constraints file:

```
# Clocks
set_property -dict {PACKAGE_PIN H19 IOSTANDARD DIFF_SSTL15} [get_ports clk_p_i];
create_clock -period 5.000 -name clk_p_i -waveform {0.000 2.500} -add [get_ports clk_p_i]

set_property -dict {PACKAGE_PIN G18 IOSTANDARD DIFF_SSTL15} [get_ports clk_n_i];
create_clock -period 5.000 -name clk_n_i -waveform {0.000 2.500} -add [get_ports clk_n_i]

# Reset button
set_property PACKAGE_PIN AV39 [get_ports reset_button_i]
set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS18 [get_ports reset_button_i]

# LED 
set_property PACKAGE_PIN AM39 [get_ports led0_o]
set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS18 [get_ports led0_o]

# Board voltage config
set_property CONFIG_VOLTAGE 1.8 [current_design]
set_property CFGBVS GND [current_design]
```

A Xilinx clocking wizard is used to take the 200MHz differential clock and produce a 50MHz single ended clock. Is this the correct to setup the clock constraints?

Comment: I'm not quite sure of the significance, but the _System Clock (SYSCLK_P and SYSCLK_N)_ section of the VC709 user guide shows ``DIFF_SSTL15_DCI`` as the ``IOSTANDARD``, rather than ``DIFF_SSTL15``.

Comment: @ChesterGillon Ah yes, I will change that. It does seem to work as is but should keep it according to user guide. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: For differential clocks you only need to constrain the P side, [see AR](https://support.xilinx.com/s/article/57109?language=en_US).

Comment: @mng Oh ok, I see. But when using a clocking wizard to create a single clock from the differential system clock, do you not need the clock_n in the constraints to instantiate with as input? Also do you have to create input / output delay constraints?

Comment: You can make a pin constraint for clock_n, but I think the tools are smart enough to recognize when you assign a differential standard. Right now you don't really need input/output delay constraints for a button and LED; at least I'd say constraining those would be an academic exercise. Constraints are more needed (and less abstract) when you are talking to other chips.